# BIP > Using system current date if date parameter is coming as null

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

In my BIP RTF template, i have two parameters "StartDate" and "EndDate". Siebel application is sending these parameters with user selected dates. Now requirement is if the dates are not sent from Siebel then BIP should use system date in "StartDate" and "EndDate".

This is my IF condition i am using to match above parameters:

```
<?if:( xdoxslt:format_date(IssueDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd','mm/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE))>= (xdoxslt:format_date($StartDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd','mm/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE)) and (xdoxslt:format_date(IssueDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd','mm/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE))<= (xdoxslt:format_date($EndDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd','mm/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE))?>
```

I am not sure how can i can do it.

Kindly help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Have the system that's sending the XML to BI Publisher do an NVL on the date parameter.

Comment: what that means?

Comment: Sorry, meant date, not data.

Comment: User can select date or send null

Comment: Right. Assuming it's anything like Oracle EBS, there's a place to store the definition of the XML generation. In Oracle EBS it's called the Data Definition, and its stored int he BI Publisher module. The data definition contains all the select statements and data grouping/hierarchy.  The other option is to have a PL/SQL package generate the XML, and the select statements and XML building would be inside that. Find where the XML is built, and in the select statement, use a NVL similar function to put sysdate if parameter date is NULL.

Comment: Hi, sorry this is not EBS.

Comment: The situation is still applicable.  Something is making the XML between when the user enters parameters, and when its sent to BI Publisher. That's where you would convert the NULL value to the current system date.

Comment: Looks like you need to create, or edit the existing, Integration Object. https://bestcrmmarket.wordpress.com/2016/03/17/how-to-create-a-siebel-report-using-bi-publisher/

Comment: what format should i use in IC level? Anything on that? In the link nothing is new.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have zero Siebel experience.

Comment: so lets wait for the one with experience :)